# Get epoch for a specific date using Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

How do I convert `07/26/2010` to a UNIX timestamp using Javascript?

Answer (score 256, accepted):

You can create a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object, and call [`getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) on it:

```
new Date(2010, 6, 26).getTime() / 1000
```

Comment: The month argument for the date constructor lacks a little consistency and is actually zero-based.  This means 7 is August, so you need to subtract 1 :-)

Comment: @Andy - it is a whacky idea to offset months by -1 while keeping the rest, and is exactly the kind of thing that can make a space shuttle go nuts, if JavaScript were ever to be used there :)

Comment: Probably better to go: new Date("2010-7-26").getTime() / 1000 so you don't have to think about offsets.

Comment: @Vincent: `new Date("2010-7-26")` will not parse in Internet Explorer.  *Date* constructor relies on the *Date.parse()* method when a string is passed, which is implementation dependant in ECMA-262 3rd edition and, as a result, notoriously inflexible in IE.

Comment: One could minimize possible errors or misunderstandings specifying the time zone too. At least the actual (Linux-) versions of Firefox, Opera and Chrome support to instantiate a JavaScript Date like
new Date("Jan 1, 1970 GMT+00:00, 00:01");
which also reduces confusion about the correct month format.

Answer (score 65):

```
new Date("2016-3-17").valueOf()
```

will return a long epoch

Answer (score 11):

Some answers does not explain the side effects of variations in the timezone for JavaScript Date object.  So you should consider this answer if this is a concern for you.

**Method 1: Machine's timezone dependent**

By default, JavaScript returns a Date considering the machine's timezone, so `getTime()` result varies from computer to computer.  You can check this behavior running:

```
new Date(1970, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).getTime()
    // Since 1970-01-01 is Epoch, you may expect ZERO
    // but in fact the result varies based on computer's timezone
```

This is not a problem if you really want the time since Epoch considering your timezone.  So if you want to get time since Epoch for the current Date or even a specified Date based on the **computer's timezone**, you're free to continue using this method.

```
// Seconds since Epoch (Unix timestamp format)

new Date().getTime() / 1000             // local Date/Time since Epoch in seconds
new Date(2020, 11, 1).getTime() / 1000  // time since Epoch to 2020-12-01 00:00 (local timezone) in seconds

// Milliseconds since Epoch (used by some systems, eg. JavaScript itself)

new Date().getTime()                    // local Date/Time since Epoch in milliseconds
new Date(2020,  0, 2).getTime()         // time since Epoch to 2020-01-02 00:00 (local timezone) in milliseconds

// **Warning**: notice that MONTHS in JavaScript Dates starts in zero (0 = January, 11 = December)
```

---

**Method 2: Machine's timezone independent**

However, if you want to get ride of variations in timezone and get time since Epoch for **a specified Date in UTC** (that is, timezone independent), you need to use `Date.UTC` method or shift the date from your timezone to UTC:

```
Date.UTC(1970,  0, 1)
    // should be ZERO in any computer, since it is ZERO the difference from Epoch

    // Alternatively (if, for some reason, you do not want Date.UTC)
    const timezone_diff = new Date(1970, 0, 1).getTime()  // difference in milliseconds between your timezone and UTC
    (new Date(1970,  0, 1).getTime() - timezone_diff)
    // should be ZERO in any computer, since it is ZERO the difference from Epoch
```

So, using this method (or, alternatively, subtracting the difference), the result should be:

```
// Seconds since Epoch (Unix timestamp format)

Date.UTC(2020,  0, 1) / 1000  // time since Epoch to 2020-01-01 00:00 UTC in seconds

    // Alternatively (if, for some reason, you do not want Date.UTC)
    const timezone_diff = new Date(1970, 0, 1).getTime()
    (new Date(2020,  0, 1).getTime() - timezone_diff) / 1000  // time since Epoch to 2020-01-01 00:00 UTC in seconds
    (new Date(2020, 11, 1).getTime() - timezone_diff) / 1000  // time since Epoch to 2020-12-01 00:00 UTC in seconds

// Milliseconds since Epoch (used by some systems, eg. JavaScript itself)

Date.UTC(2020,  0, 2)   // time since Epoch to 2020-01-02 00:00 UTC in milliseconds

    // Alternatively (if, for some reason, you do not want Date.UTC)
    const timezone_diff = new Date(1970, 0, 1).getTime()
    (new Date(2020,  0, 2).getTime() - timezone_diff)         // time since Epoch to 2020-01-02 00:00 UTC in milliseconds

// **Warning**: notice that MONTHS in JavaScript Dates starts in zero (0 = January, 11 = December)
```

IMO, unless you know what you're doing (see note above), you should prefer **Method 2**, since it is machine independent.

---

**End note**

Although the recomendations in this answer, and since `Date.UTC` does not work without a specified date/time, you may be inclined in using the alternative approach and doing something like this:

```
const timezone_diff = new Date(1970, 0, 1).getTime()
(new Date().getTime() - timezone_diff)  // <-- !!! new Date() without arguments
    // means "local Date/Time subtracted by timezone since Epoch" (?)
```

This does not make any sense and it is probably **WRONG** (you are modifying the date).  Be aware of not doing this.  If you want to get time since Epoch from the current date *AND TIME*, you are most probably OK using **Method 1**.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

There is a function `UTC()` that returns the milliseconds from the unix epoch.

Answer (score 5):

`Date.parse()` method parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of milliseconds since `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC`.

```
const unixTimeZero = Date.parse('01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT');
const javaScriptRelease = Date.parse('04 Dec 1995 00:12:00 GMT');

console.log(unixTimeZero);
// expected output: 0

console.log(javaScriptRelease);
// expected output: 818035920000
```

Explore more at: [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Date.now() function.

Comment: Technically did not answer the OP question of converting a _particular_ date to seconds-since-the-epoch. But I like the concise-ness. Clearly `Date.now()` is better than `new Date().getTime()` in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
Number(new Date(2010, 6, 26))
```

Works the same way as things above. If you need seconds don't forget to `/ 1000`