# One year back query datetime

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get all records from now between a year ago but it's not working exactly.
Made in CodeIgniter

This is my query , antything wrong with it ? :

```
    $currentDate = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");
    $yeardate=date('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime('-1 year'));
    $this->db->select('TimeStamp');
    $this->db->where('Transaction', 'COMPLETED');
    $this->db->where('TimeStamp>=',$yeardate);
    $this->db->where('TimeStamp<=',$currentDate);
    $query = $this->db->get('R_Logs');
    $results = $query->result();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Define `not working exactly.`.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add a space between TimeStamp <= and TimeStamp >= .
My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be easier to try Epoch time and then query off of that - e.g. [Get epoch for a specific date using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367415/get-epoch-for-a-specific-date-using-javascript)

That will convert the date to number of days since January 1, 1970. then from that you can subtract 365 days ( or use the yearInteger %4 trick to find out if it is a leap year)

Answer (score 0):

Change these two lines any try once:

```
$currentDate    = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$yeardate       = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' -1 year');
```

Dump your query and debug:

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```