# Calculate duration between two date times in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I need to calculate the duration between two datetimes in JavaScript. I have tried this code:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;  //Current Date
console.log("current date"+today);


var valuestart ="8:00 AM";
var valuestop = "4:00 PM";//$("select[name='timestop']").val();

//create date format          
var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + valuestart).getHours();
var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2007 " + valuestop).getHours();

var hourDiff = timeEnd - timeStart;             
console.log("duration"+hourDiff);
```

From this, I am able to get Current Date and duration. But when I replace the date "01/01/2007" with the variable "today", I am getting the result as NaN. Please guide me in where I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure `timeStart` & `timeEnd` are valid dates?

Comment: Show us the code that's not working.  Right now 'today' is a Date object

Comment: Its correct in the above code.But when i change that into var timeStart=new Date(""+today+""+valuestart+"").getHours(); and similar in timeEnd, i am getting problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;  //Current Date

        var valuestart ="8:00 AM";
        var valuestop = "4:00 PM";//$("select[name='timestop']").val();

        //create date format  
        var timeStart = new Date(today + " " + valuestart).getHours();
        var timeEnd = new Date(today + " " + valuestop).getHours();

        var hourDiff = timeEnd - timeStart;  
        alert("duration:"+hourDiff);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should work on the epoch milliseconds.
The idea is to transform everything to the [epoch millis representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367415/get-epoch-for-a-specific-date-using-javascript), perform your [calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623783/get-the-time-difference-between-two-datetimes), then go back to another format if needed.

There are many articles on the subject:

- [Get the time difference between two datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623783/get-the-time-difference-between-two-datetimes)
- http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/calculating-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript.html#fbid=AojoSIQKaAL

Answer (score 1):

today is of Date type whereas "01/01/2007" is a string. Trying to concatenate a Date object with "8:00 AM" will not work. You will have to turn today variable into a string or use today.setHours(8)

Comment: How to convert Date type into string

Comment: If you have jQuery, it will be easy. $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yyyy', today);

Comment: If you do not have jQuery, you will likely have to use the built-in methods from the Date object to build the string: (today.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + today.getDate() + '/' + today.getFullYear(). Something like that.

Comment: No i have not suppose to use datepicker.I will get the time from server

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It's a little bit late. I second the answer from Christophe Roussy.
First, calculate the difference in UTC format, then turn the unit - hour.
I think it's easier to understand and maintain.
Here's the code

```js
var date1 = new Date(`some_valid_start_date_format`);
var date2 = new Date(`some_end_start_date_format`);

var duration = date2.valueOf() - date1.valueOf(); // The unit is millisecond
var hourDiff = parseInt(duration / (60 * 60 * 1000)) // Turn the duration into hour format
```

Comment: Think you need some brackets around that duration line:

`parseInt(duration / (60 * 60 * 1000))`

Comment: ok, edited, thx for the correctness

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Nice and succinct, I used it in my program :-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried [`luxon`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#duration) and it's very handy:

Given `dt1` and `dt2` as ISO representation of date time,

```
luxon.DateTime.fromISO(dt1).diff(
  luxon.DateTime.fromISO(dt2),
  ['years', 'months', 'days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']
).values
```

Answer (score 0):

## Simple Solution

If your duration is guaranteed to be less than 24 hours and you want to display it to the user here is a very simple solution:

```js
function formatDuration(millis) {
    return new Date(millis).toISOString().substring(11, 19);
}

console.log(formatDuration(59999));    // 00:00:59
console.log(formatDuration(3599999));  // 00:59:59
console.log(formatDuration(86399999)); // 23:59:59
```

## Better Solution

If you want to support years, months & days:

```js
function formatDuration(millis) {
    let date = new Date(millis);
    let parts = [];

    if (date.getUTCFullYear() > 1970) {
        let years = date.getUTCFullYear() - 1970;
        parts.push(years, pluralize(years, 'year'));
    }
    if (date.getUTCMonth() > 0) { // months start at zero
        let months = date.getUTCMonth();
        parts.push(months, pluralize(months, 'month'));
    }
    if (date.getUTCDate() > 1) {
        let days = date.getUTCDate() - 1;
        parts.push(days, pluralize(days, 'day'));
    }

    parts.push(date.toISOString().substring(11, 19));

    return parts.join(' ');
}

function pluralize(count, singular, plural) {
    return count === 1 ? singular : plural ?? `${singular}s`;
}

console.log(formatDuration(new Date('1970-01-01T00:00:59.999Z').getTime())); // 00:00:59
console.log(formatDuration(new Date('1970-01-01T00:59:59.999Z').getTime())); // 00:59:59
console.log(formatDuration(new Date('1970-01-01T23:59:59.999Z').getTime())); // 23:59:59
console.log(formatDuration(new Date('1970-01-31T23:59:59.999Z').getTime())); // 30 days 23:59:59
console.log(formatDuration(new Date('1970-12-01T23:59:59.999Z').getTime())); // 11 months 23:59:59
console.log(formatDuration(new Date('1970-12-31T23:59:59.999Z').getTime())); // 11 months 30 days 23:59:59
console.log(formatDuration(new Date('1971-01-01T23:59:59.999Z').getTime())); // 1 year 23:59:59
console.log(formatDuration(new Date('1971-01-31T23:59:59.999Z').getTime())); // 1 year 30 days 23:59:59
console.log(formatDuration(new Date('1971-12-01T23:59:59.999Z').getTime())); // 1 year 11 months 23:59:59
console.log(formatDuration(new Date('1971-12-31T23:59:59.999Z').getTime())); // 1 year 11 months 30 days 23:59:59
```

If you want to include the milliseconds use this substring instead:

```
.substring(11, 23) // 23:59:59.999
```

and for completeness the JSDoc:

```js
/**
 * Formats a number of milliseconds to `HH:mm:ss`.
 * For durations of 24h and longer, prefixes the number of years, months, days if any are at least 1.
 * Examples:
 * * `00:00:59`
 * * `00:59:59`
 * * `23:59:59`
 * * `30 days 23:59:59`
 * * `11 months 23:59:59`
 * * `11 months 30 days 23:59:59`
 * * `1 year 23:59:59`
 * * `1 year 30 days 23:59:59`
 * * `1 year 11 months 23:59:59`
 * * `1 year 11 months 30 days 23:59:59`
 * @param {number} millis milliseconds
 * @return {string} the time portion in ISO format (excluding milliseconds) i.e. 23:59:59
 */
```