# match values start or end dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datetime, match

I am facing an issue in javascript dates, i want to match `slot dates` comparing `start_date or end_date.`

my component

```
  {this.state.data && this.state.data.length
            ? this.state.data
                .filter(data => {
                  const date = new Date(data.start_date);
                  const enddate = new Date(data.end_date);
                  console.log(date); //start
                  console.log(enddate); //end
                  return date > prevDate && date < nextDate;
                })
                .map(({ cust_full_name, start_date }, index) => (
                  <div class="row" key={index}>
                    slot: {index + 1}
                    <p>{start_date}</p>
                    <p>{cust_full_name}</p>
                  </div>
                ))
            : null}
```

working demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-dream-gl3l7?file=/src/App.js

what should i do? can anyone help me?

Comment: In your demo, where are `this.state.newprevious` and `this.state.newseconddate` defined?

Comment: sorry i updated code you check it `this.state.slot1` and `this.state.slot2`

Comment: plz help me , i try to solve this issue i did lot of time on it [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3674623/anthony-mcgrath)

Comment: `return date > prevDate && date < nextDate` should use  `>=` instead of `>` to get the `//match with slot1` record

Comment: You should start by clearly stating your question and posting sample code and data with expected outcome here, not on some other site.

Comment: can you make `codesandbox` example plz [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3674623/anthony-mcgrath)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Your slot values in your state are in arrays but when you pass them to date you aren't accessing the string value.

slot1 : ["date"]
Incorrect: `new Date[slot1]`
Correct: `new Date[slot[0]]`

In your sandbox it seems you never populated `newprevious` and `newseconddate` here:

```
const prevDate = new Date(this.state.newprevious);
const nextDate = new Date(this.state.newseconddate);
```

Once i populated those in the above state section, it seems to work. I do also suggest maybe turning Date into something like epoch; so the numbers are easier to work with ([Get epoch for a specific date using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367415/get-epoch-for-a-specific-date-using-javascript))

Comment: sorry i updated code you check it `this.state.slot1 and this.state.slot` [@](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367415/get-epoch-for-a-specific-date-using-javascript)

Comment: plz help me , i try to solve this issue i did lot of time on it [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6580912/xpaillant)

Comment: @adnankhan thanks for updating! Your slot1,2,3,4 are in arrays. so you would have to to do this.state.slot1[0]. 

Also the current way slot 1 still wont match because 3:00 > 3:00 won't be true, so maybe make it 3:00 >= 3:00 in (`date > prevDate`)

Comment: can you make `codesandbox` example plz then can help me [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6580912/xpaillant)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-saha-gupff?file=/src/App.js
check updates lines 40-46 and 68-71

Comment: your `App.js` code is not show [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6580912/xpaillant)

Comment: @adnankhan apologies, https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-cartwright-cbtrk?file=/src/App.js. hope this helps!